# Initialize an Empty Array of Tuples in Julia

Tags: julia

I can't figure out how to initialize an empty array of tuples. The [manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#tuple-types) says:

> The type of a tuple of values is the tuple of types of values... Accordingly, a tuple of types can be used anywhere a type is expected.

Yet this does not work:

```
myarray = (Int64,Int64)[]
```

But this does:

```
Int64[]
```

It would seem a type is expected in front of the empty square brackets, but the tuple type doesn't work. This `<type>[]` syntax is the only way I can find to get an empty typed Array (other methods seem to produce a bunch of `#undef` values). Is the only way to do it, and if it is, how can I type the Array with tuples?

BTW, my use case is creating an array of initially indeterminate length and pushing tuples onto it in a loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do `Array((Int,Int),0)` for this. It is probably feasible to add methods to `getindex` to make `(Int,Int)[]` work, but I'm not sure it's worth it. Feel free to open an issue.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works and I've added the issue. I think it's definitely worth it-- it's really confusing when the actual language syntax is not consistent with what the manual says.

Answer (score 13):

For people who look for the latest solution,

`Tuple{Int, Int}[]` works in v0.4

Also the verbose way `Array{Tuple{Int, Int}}(0)` works in v0.4 as well.

It creates a `0-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}`

Note that in v1.0 you'd need to write

`Array{Tuple{Int, Int}}(undef, 0)`