# creating 2 dimensional array of unspecified (varying) size

Tags: arrays, julia

Newbie question: I want to dynamically create an integer 2D array `M[i,j]`, whose sizes (in both dimensions) are unknown beforehand. Moreover, for each index `i`, the size of the i-th row may vary.

Question 1: How do I declare such an array (do I even have to)? I have tried `Array[]`, `Array(Int64,1...)`, and `Array((Int,Int),0)`as in [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419124/initialize-an-empty-array-of-tuples-in-julia?rq=1) and others.

Question 2: once created, how to I populate the array in a smart and concise way? Say my i-th row is suppose to be equal to a given 1-dimensional `B`, I would like to write

```
A[i] = B
```

or

```
A[i,:] = B
```

or even

```
A[i,1:n] = B
```

where `n` is the size of `B`. All of these give me a `BoundsError()`. Slicemight do the trick, but I cannot make it agree with my declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a 2D array here, because in a 2D array all rows are of the same size. Instead, you want a vector-of-vectors. For example:

```
A = Array(Vector{Int}, 5)
A[1] = rand(1:10, 3)
A[2] = rand(1:100, 22)
```

If you inspect `A`, you'll see something like this:

```
julia> A
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
    [5,7,7]                                                        
    [1,63,40,86,61,39,98,5,68,97  …  78,49,44,89,48,63,90,90,86,83]
 #undef                                                            
 #undef                                                            
 #undef
```

Another great tool is to use a comprehension:

```
julia> A = Vector{Int}[ [1:m] for m = 1:5]
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]        
 [1,2]      
 [1,2,3]    
 [1,2,3,4]  
 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The main thing you'll want to be careful about is that each element of `A` is a *reference* to a vector; if you assign

```
A[1] = b
A[2] = b
```

then any change to `b` will affect *both* `A[1]` and `A[2]`. If you don't want that, use

```
A[1] = copy(b)
A[2] = copy(b)
```

Comment: You said "you want a vector-of-vectors" but it reads to me like you declared an array of vectors.  I'm still new to the differences between arrays and vectors in julia, though, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `Vector{T}` is a typealias for `Array{T,1}`: see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/array.jl#L3. So vectors are just 1-d arrays, nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Thanks tholy for clearing things up. Not only does it work, but I'm moving forward in my understanding of julia. The warning on using `copy` is welcome ! To sum up, what matters here is using a _vector of vector_ instead of a 2D array, whose horizontal dimension would be fixed. I may add for the reader, that you access the values by typing `A[i][j]`.